# Why is my blender export to GLTF missing some faces?

Tags: export, gltf

[image][image]I created a model for a building in blender. To create the building I export .dwg plan of the building from autoCAD, then I converted it to .dfx for import into blender after which I extruded the walls to create the 3D model. All looks well in blender but when I try to export it as GLTF, I notice that some walls are missing. What could be the problem?

Comment: Probably face orientation by the sound of it. This can happen if you extrude in the "wrong" direction. In Edit mode, select All then SHIFT-N to recalculate normals and try exporting again. If that doesn't help we'll need to see some images which you can drag and drop into your question

Comment: Thank you, I have done that and re exported but still no change, and I have added the images to the question.

Comment: Are the walls visible from the "wrong" side?  I'm wondering if [Backface Culling needs to be turned off](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#double-sided-backface-culling).